# How to set topmargin = leftmargin when the latter is auto-completed in geometry?

Tags: margins, geometry

I'd like to set the top margin being equal to the left margin, but the left margin is auto-completed from the text width. I'm using `geometry` package.

I just want to do something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    textwidth = 38em, 
    top = left, 
}
```

Comment: @HarishKumar: I've tried that but it gives a crazy result, so maybe `\leftmargin` isn't related to this similarly to `\topmargin`. The left margin is autocompleted by `geometry` package from given text width and left–right margin ratio.

Comment: @HarishKumar: I think that my question isn't related to document class. I've added an example.

Comment: @HarishKumar: I'm using oneside, a4paper, 12pt, article. But how is it related to my question of how to relate top with left using `geometry`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `\leftmargin`, as [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) mentions in the [users' manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf):

> Each margin is measured from the corresponding edge of a paper. 
>   For example, left margin (inner margin) means a horizontal distance
>   between the left (inner) edge of the paper and that of the total body.
>   Therefore the left and top margins defined in `geometry` are different
>   from the native dimensions `\leftmargin` and `\topmargin`.

`geometry`'s left margin is stored in `\Gm@lmargin`, which you can access as a package option using

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\geometry{top=\Gm@lmargin}}\x
\makeatother
```

I would therefore use

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  textwidth = 38em
}
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\geometry{top=\Gm@lmargin}}\x
\makeatother
```

Comment: So it is really not supported by the package, you have to use a workaround. I suppose that I cannot use `\geometry{textwidth=38em,top=\Gm@lmargin}` since the correct left margin is not set yet, but why cannot I use `\geometry{textwidth=38em}\geometry{top=\Gm@lmargin}`?

Comment: @user87690: Good question...

Comment: I suppose I may hide the expansion trick in a macro: `\newcommand\Expanded[1]{\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup#1}\x}` and then call simply `\Expanded{\noexpand\geometry{top = \Gm@lmargin}}`.